# Pandas If a value exists in one column populate value in different column

Tags: python, pandas

| product group | product | Record Type | Main Product Family |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PMX | PMX_IA | bte-pmx | PMX |
| GTRate | FM | bt_us-FM | GTRate |
|  |  | bte-pmx |  |

I have the above dataframe and have added the column Main Product Family. IF there are values in the column "Product Group" I map these values to the Main Product Family column. If there are null values I need to go off of Record Type.

I have tried the following to populate values in the Main Product Family.

```
def func(x):
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
       if x.iloc[i,2] == 'bte-pmx':
           x.iloc[i,3] == 'PMX'
    return x
```

And then I try to map this function to the dataframe but nothing populates in the rows with null values in Main Product Family.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems easier and clearer (I bet faster too)

```
i = x['Record Type'] == 'bte-pmx'        # select your rows
x.loc[i,'Main Product Family'] == 'PMX'  # set values in those rows
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
df['Main Product Family'] = df['product group'].where(df['product group'].notna(),df['Record Type'])
```